What is the most common way of telling people to stay hydrated?
I asked on some forums and so far I got a few different replies. Based on what DeepL translates them to, two of them seem the most reasonable to me, which are "水分を忘れないでね！" and "水分補給を欠かすな！". Is one of them correct in the sense that it's the common way a person would suggest a friend to stay hydrated? Or do they just stress different parts of the sentence or something? My japanese is still very basic, so I don't really undestand what they're saying, but I'd love to learn a little.
If this is the wrong forum for my question, feel free to close this thread. Thanks in advance.
Context:

It's supposed for a tshirt, so I just want the most casual way possible. I guess it would make more sense if it is a reminder, because the graphic my friend is drawing is a skeleton inside a bottle, so it's supposed to be a kind of morbid joke. Assume the speaker is a male high school student talking to his male friend who is about the same age. A bit younger if necessary.


The difference between 忘れないでね and 欠かすな is basically the degree of politeness. I guess that is not your concern here?

@YusukeMatsubara not really, but in that case I'd like to use the less polite/more casual version. I suppose that's 欠かすな?

You probably haven't got a definite answer because your question lacks a lot of aspects of information. e.g.: what kind of person is the speaker, and "the friend", what gender, what age, in what situation is it uttered, is it the first time callout or reminder? If you want a phrase to fill the blank in an existing poster, sign, or dialogue, please show it.

@broccoliforest Thanks for pointing that out. It's supposed for a tshirt, so I just want the most casual way possible. I guess it would make more sense if it is a reminder, because the graphic my friend is drawing is a skeleton inside a bottle, so it's supposed to be a kind of morbid joke. Assume the speaker is a male high school student talking to his male friend who is about the same age. A bit younger if necessary.

It is not "the most common way" (I doubt there is any such), but given the context:

It's supposed for a tshirt, so I just want the most casual way possible. I guess it would make more sense if it is a reminder, because the graphic my friend is drawing is a skeleton inside a bottle, so it's supposed to be a kind of morbid joke. Assume the speaker is a male high school student talking to his male friend who is about the same age. A bit younger if necessary.

I can come up with almost only one option:

水分【すいぶん】は摂【と】ろうね！

Basically, 水分を摂る translates into "get hydrated", and 摂る > 摂ろう + ね makes it friendly command, or suggestion, towards a general virtue: "(why don't you) get hydrated". The role of that は replacing を is important and a bit tricky to explain in textbook terms, but it often signals the bottom line among instructions, which would be taken as an humor like "... or you'll be like me" said by a skeleton.
Possible variations are: な instead ね to make it sound jock speech if you want; and とろう instead of kanji 摂ろう if you assume younger readers.
